# RxJs and redux-observable. Append value when ajax succeed or failed

Tags: redux, rxjs, axios, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have the following epic:

```
export const changeTeamSubscriptionPlan = (braintreePlanId: string) => ({
  type: CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN,
  braintreePlanId,
});

export const changeTeamSubscriptionPlanEpic = (action$: any, store: Store<ReduxState, *>) =>
  action$.ofType(CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN)
    .mergeMap(({ braintreePlanId }) => {
      const state = store.getState();
      const { subscription_id } = state.payment.subscription;
      let request;
      if (subscription_id) {
        request = ajax(api.changeTeamSubscriptionPlan(subscription_id, braintreePlanId));
      } else {
        const [method] = state.payment.paymentMethods;
        request = ajax(api.createSubscription(braintreePlanId, method.token));
      }

      // I would like to emit another value ({ type: FETCH_TEAM }) no matter what happens 
      //(basically I try to invalidate the team data even if the request fails)
      return request
        .map(response => ({
          type: CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN + SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            data: response.response,
            status: response.status,
          },
        }))
        .catch(error => Observable.of({
          type: CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN + FAILURE,
          response: {
            data: error.xhr.response,
            status: error.xhr.status,
          },
        }));
    });
```

What I want to do is no matter if `ajax` call ends with **catch** or calls **map** I want to append another value.

I run out of ideas, so I'm hoping for help.

Comment: can you switch out the custom operators for standard ones so it's more clear?

Comment: @jayphelps I've included their definitions for now. They may be kind of weird though...

Comment: Is it actually running your `mapFailure` code, or is an error thrown elsewhere which you are not trapping?

Comment: @Mikkel yes. When request fails mapFailure is called to map error reponse.

Comment: So your objective is to avoid errors, so that you can return a value (even though it may be an error code), but your code just passes on the error - surely you don't want to do this?

Comment: @Mikkel yes. But `ajax` throws the error when request not succeeded and this makes the observable chain to break (afaik). https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: @jayphelps I have switched custom operators in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to original operators it turned out that I can do this:

```
  return request
    .map(response => ({
      type: CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN + SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        data: response.response,
        status: response.status,
      },
    }))
    .catch(error => Observable.of({
      type: CHANGE_TEAM_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN + FAILURE,
      error: mapToError(error),
    }))
    .concat(Observable.of({ type: 'CHUJ_TYPE' }));
```

and `concat` will append value **even** when the catch block fires.

I was originally using custom operator which I though will work just like `catch` does but will reduce boilerplate in my app:

```
Observable.prototype.mapFailure = function catchAndMapError(ACTION_TYPE, optionalPayload = {}) {
  return Observable.create(subscriber =>
    this.subscribe(
      value => subscriber.next(value),
      (error) => {
        try {
          const action = {
            type: ACTION_TYPE + FAILURE,
            error: {
              ...mapToError(error),
              ...optionalPayload,
            },
          };
          subscriber.next(action);
        } catch (e) { // catch mappings error
          subscriber.error(e);
        }
      },
      () => subscriber.complete(),
    ),
  );
};
```

It seems like it doesn't work the same as `catch`.....

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding: `catch` truly catches the error, preventing it from propagating. So the `concat` being applied after it means that the concat will subscribe to the provided argument after the source completes (after the observable returned in catch completes) If you only want to concat if and only if there was no ajax error, you can put the concat above the catch. The ajax error will propagate to the catch, bypassing the concat.

Comment: @jayphelps Actually I want to dispatch an action after the request completed (with failure or not) so the epic with standard operators and `concat` seems to work that way.